# return value in action server

Tags: actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm following this tutorial  http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib , and my question is,

The server can return a value to the client? How can I do?

thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203420/return-value-in-action-server/) by [rcj1986](https://answers.ros.org/users/14706/rcj1986/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2015-02-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a short snippet sn section 5 of the page you linked:

```
# Define the goal
uint32 dishwasher_id  # Specify which dishwasher we want to use
---
# Define the result
uint32 total_dishes_cleaned
---
# Define a feedback message
float32 percent_complete
```

See the line with `# Define the result`? The return type of this action is `uint32` and the name of the return value is `total_dishes_cleaned`.

To set this return value have a look at the `setSucceeded()` signature found [here](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/actionlib/html/classactionlib_1_1SimpleActionServer.html#a063a4f5279ee8de856e10d1b612402ba):

```
void actionlib::SimpleActionServer< ActionSpec >::setSucceeded(const Result &   result = Result(),
    const std::string &     
    text = std::string("") 
)
```

You can call `setSucceeded()` with a result as parameter. In this result object you can set the return members.

In Python it works the same.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2015-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rcj1986](https://answers.ros.org/users/14706/rcj1986/) on 2015-02-20**:
Thank you for your reply.

Do you know if it's possible declare the result like a geometry_msgs::Pose or only the "normal" type of variables (float, int, etc)?

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-02-20**:
Yes this works. Just do `package_name/MessageName`